# Push array back in key

Tags: php, arrays

I will always unset an array value in my Site request.

```
unset($segments[0]);
```

How can I push back the arrays, so I get the "1" key to be the "0"?

Example:

```
$arr[0] = 'Balls';
$arr[1] = 'Test';

unset($arr[0]);

(magicalfunctionthatpushback)

echo $arr[0]; //Test
```

There must be a function for this or do I need to use a for loop?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`array_shift`](http://php.net/array_shift) to remove the element instead of unset.

There's also the [array_values](http://php.net/array_values) function to get a new array reindexed from zero. I would choose `array_shift()` in your scenario though.

Comment: +1 I didn't realize `array_shift()` would renumber numeric keys